# Regex replacement of php in urlencode()

Tags: php, regex

All hail Regex!

In PHP:
From this:

`urlencode($row_rs_details['Title'],ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');`

and several hundred more where the variable names are different, I need to remove the ,ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'
 and just have this:

```
 urlencode($row_rs_details['Title']);
```

while leaving the many different $row_rs_names intact.

Sincere thanks for saving me at least six hours.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://ideone.com/aBameT)? See a [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/yQ1xC2/1).

Comment: @stribizhev Hold on, that should do it. Please post this as your answer and I'll upvote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
(urlencode\(\$[^][]*\['Title'\]),ENT_QUOTES,\s*'utf-8'\);
```

And replace with `$1);`.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yQ1xC2/1)

It is basically matches and captures the first part beginning from `urlencode` and up to and including `['Title']`, the rest is matched, but is later removed during the replace operation. The captured text is restored in the result with the `$1` back-reference and a literal `);`.

Here is a PHP code demo:

```
$re = '/(urlencode\(\$[^][]*\[\'Title\'\]),ENT_QUOTES,\s*\'utf-8\'\);/'; 
$str = "urlencode(\$row_rs_details['Title'],ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');"; 
$subst = "$1);"; 
echo $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
```

Result: `urlencode($row_rs_details['Title']);`

Comment: Thanks for that help. Tip of the hat to the wizards.

Answer (score 1):

Occam's razor. You don't need regex for this. Just do a simple find and replace for the search string `urlencode($row_rs_details['Title'],ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');` with `urlencode($row_rs_details['Title']);` as the target string.

Comment: There are hundreds of others with that which don't need changed. I'm specifically looking for those with 'Title'

Comment: @AllThisOnAnACER: Updated the answer. If you need something more specific, please consider providing a bigger snippet of the text you'll be processing.

Comment: Well there are hundreds of these very similarly coded. Some are in url's some are in pages. I don't want to find them all and screw up most of them, I simply want to target those that have the aforementioned format. Thanks for your help

Comment: @AllThisOnAnACER: Please update the question so it contains enough information to answer it. We don't need an exhaustive list of examples, but we do need a description that lets us know which parts of the string can vary and how. (While you're at it, you might want to improve the title, and perhaps specify what language and/or library you're using; there are a lot of different varieties of regular expressions.)

Comment: @AllThisOnAnACER: Sorry, but your examples do not seem sufficiently clear. Could you add a bigger snippet to your question? What are some examples where the regex should not identify the search string?

Comment: @Roney Michael. Thanks for your patience, let me create a better example. Hold on...

Comment: I have many with 
     `urlencode($row_rsMat_Rec['Title'],ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')`

and many with 

     `htmlspecialchars($row_rsReceived['Title'],ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')` 

that I don't want to change. So I'm searching specifically for
        `urlencode($row_rs_details['Title'],ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');` to change.
Is that clearer?

Comment: @AllThisOnAnACER: I've edited it again to basically look for and replace the entire thing. Is there still some case that might be incorrectly identified?

Comment: @Roney Michael - I don't see your answer. Did it post?

Comment: @Keith Thompson - Thanks, let's try this: it is in PHP

     `urlencode($row_rs_details['Title'],ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');`

the part that can vary is the 
     `$row_rs_details`

 and the part I want to remove is the `,ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'`

Comment: @Roney Michael - Thanks for taking the time to help me. Sorry I wasn't clearer at the start..

Comment: @AllThisOnAnACER: The update needs to be in the question. Most readers aren't going to see these comments. And again, you should fix the title; a lot of readers are going to see "Regex replacement of" and move on without reading the question.